# PHP/CSS Random Background

Tags: php, html, css, random, background

Trying to get a random background between two images.

The PHP (Before Doctype in index.php):

```
<?php
$bg = array('back1.jpg', 'back2.jpg' ); // array of filenames
$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #474747;
  font: 13px/23px  'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  min-width: 1186px;
  background: url( ../img/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The issue is that the background isn't set to either of the images!

EDIT:

Ive moved on to a completley PHP method although it errors:

```
Line : 5,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'
```

Code:

```
<?php
  $bg = array('back1.jpg', 'back2.jpg' ); // array of filenames
  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was   chosen
  $('body').css( {                        'background-image': 'url( img / ' +     echo $selectedBg + ')'            } );
?>
```

Comment: this `$('body').css( {...` is JS/jQuery and doesn't belong in your PHP and isn't PHP code, that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: I know, Ive moved it into my script side of things and it still wont set it

Comment: I don't know what you're telling me here. I mentioned that you have Javascript/jQuery code inside PHP and it doesn't work like that; hence, the syntax error. You need to seperate your JS from your PHP and make sure the jQuery library is loaded. E.G. http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Yes, Ive separated the code. Although it still doesn't want to work.

Comment: your question's code says otherwise. You need to edit your question with the exact code you're using and in what way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css file should have something like this in it

```
.one {
background: url(../img/back1.jpg);
}

.two {
background: url(../img/back2.jpg);
}

.three {
background: url(../img/back3.jpg);
}
```

And your HTML should have

```
<body class="<? echo $img ?>">
```

And then your PHP need only define `$img` as either `one` `two` or `three`

```
<?
$list = array('one', 'two', 'three' );
$i = array_rand($list);
$img = $list[$i];
?>
```

Comment: You would expose all your image files on the web isn't it? with PHP array_rand() you still keep some confidential. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for would be

```
array_rand();
```

PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

for your PHP:

```
<?php
$bg = array('back1.jpg', 'back2.jpg' ); // array of filenames
$i = array_rand($bg); // generate random number size of the array
$selectedBg = $bg[$i]; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

Comment: Aha, I should clarify! The name oft he images is stored its just the background isn't set to the image.

Comment: The cleanest way to do this would be separate classes for each background and then just randomise the class with PHP instead of physically modifying the CSS with it.

Comment: @jacob Explain please